# pseudo-inverse by SVD decomposition has not accurate results?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse-problems

The goal is finding  $\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial {\bf{A}}}} = 0$
where $ f\left( {{\bf{A}},{\boldsymbol{\alpha }}} \right) =
 {\left( {{{\bf{p}}^{\bf{T}}}{{\bf{A}}^{\bf{T}}}{\boldsymbol{\alpha }}
  + \eta } \right)^2}$. 
$\bf A$ is matrix and $\boldsymbol{{p^T}{A^T}\alpha}$ is scalar.

\begin{array}{l}
{\bf{p}} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{p_{1}}}\\
{{p_{2}}}
\end{array}} \right]\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
 \to \,\,{{\bf{p}}^T} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{p_{1}}}&{{p_{2}}}
\end{array}} \right]\\
\\
{\bf{A}} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{a_{11}}}&{{a_{12}}}\\
{{a_{21}}}&{{a_{22}}}
\end{array}} \right]\,\,\, \to \,\,\,{{\bf{A}}^T} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{a_{11}}}&{{a_{21}}}\\
{{a_{12}}}&{{a_{22}}}
\end{array}} \right]\\
\\
{\boldsymbol{\alpha }} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\alpha _{1}}}\\
{{\alpha _{2}}}
\end{array}} \right]
\end{array}

Derivation of f w.r.t matrix $\bf A$ will be: 
\begin{array}{l}
2{\boldsymbol{\alpha }}\left( {{{\bf{p}}^T}{{\bf{A}}^T}{\boldsymbol{\alpha }}
 + \eta } \right){{\bf{p}}^T}=0 \end{array}
\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial {\bf{A}}}} = 0{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt}
{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt}
  \Rightarrow {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} 2{\boldsymbol{\alpha }}\left
  ( {{{\bf{p}}^T}{{\bf{A}}^T}{\boldsymbol{\alpha }} + \eta } \right){{\bf{p}}^T} = 0}\\
{}\\
{{{\bf{A}}^T} =  - \eta {{\left( {{\boldsymbol{\alpha
}}{{\bf{p}}^T}} \right)}^{ - 1}}}
\\
{\bf{A}} =  - \eta {\left( {{\bf{p}}{{\boldsymbol{\alpha }}^T}}
\right)^{ - 1}}
\end{array}
But the problem is that the rank of $\bf{p}{\boldsymbol{\alpha }^T}
$ is always one.
\
I need to put result of optimal A in an iterative algorithm, So
using regularization technique is not useful because after few
iterations matrix components go to infinity. Please kindly let me
know, Can SVD decomposition solve this problem? I used pinv function in matlab to find pseudo inverse based on SVD decomposition.But, results are not correct. I think the solution for psedu-inverse is not unique in my case, because the rank of matrix is always 1. can anyone give me good hints to solve this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can infer from $2{\boldsymbol{\alpha }}\left( \mathbf p^T \mathbf A^T {\boldsymbol{\alpha}} + \eta \right) \mathbf p^T = 0$ that $\mathbf A = -\eta \left( \mathbf p {\boldsymbol{\alpha }}^T\right)^{-1}$. The equation $2{\boldsymbol{\alpha }}\left( \mathbf p^T \mathbf A^T {\boldsymbol{\alpha}} + \eta \right) \mathbf p^T = 0$ can be rewritten as $\left( {\boldsymbol{\alpha}}^T \mathbf A \mathbf p  + \eta \right) {\boldsymbol{\alpha }}\mathbf p^T = 0$. Now:

- When ${\boldsymbol{\alpha }}=0$ or $\mathbf p=0$, every matrix $\mathbf A$ is a solution.
- When both ${\boldsymbol{\alpha }}$ and $\mathbf p$ are nonzero, the equation reduces to ${\boldsymbol{\alpha}}^T \mathbf A \mathbf p  + \eta=0$, or equivalently, $(\mathbf p^T\otimes{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}^T)\operatorname{vec}(\mathbf A)=-\eta$, where $\operatorname{vec}(\mathbf A)=(a_{11},a_{21},a_{12},a_{22})^T$ and $\mathbf p\otimes{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}=(p_1\alpha_1,\,p_1\alpha_2,\,p_2\alpha_1,\,p_2\alpha_2)^T$. This is just an ordinary linear equation in four variables. So, the solution space should be a three-dimensional affine space.

Comment: α and P are both nonzero. However, according to your solution, we have 1 equation with 4 variables. So, many solutions can exist. If you look at the question, the problem is that result can not be accurate. So the question is which solution is the best in three- dimensional affine space??  this question is equivalent to finding best inverse matrix by pseduo-inverse method in my solution.  Thanks

Comment: I need the optimal matrix A. May I know what can be the ${{\bf{p}}^T} \otimes {{\bf{\alpha }}^T}$ ?. So, I need to find inverse ${{\bf{p}}^T} \otimes {{\bf{\alpha }}^T}$. Hence, again I need the SVD decomposition method. isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that matrix is not invertible, so in your view, pinv matlab function can solve this non-invertible matrix? its rank is always 1. May you explain about the symbol you used here?

Comment: I am doing an iterative procedure to find optimal A. as you can see from above, I took derivation f w.r.t matrix A. So, in an iterative fashion I want to find optimal value of an objective function. In each iteration, the objective function should be at least equal or less than previous iterations (minimization problem). however, I did not get this obvious fact in my code. That's why I think Penrose pseudoinverse for rank one matrix inversion (Matrix A) cannot give unique solution. hence, I don't get optimal value in my objective function. Is my assumption about pseudoinverse correct or not?

Comment: @Pey When $\mathbf A$ is at least 2x2, $f$ always have infinitely many *global* minimisers. So, yes, solutions are not unique, but that doesn't mean you don't get any optimal value, because all these infinitely many solutions are optimal (they all give the smallest function value). However, if both $\mathbf p,\,{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}\ne0$, there is a unique solution *that has minimum norm*: $\mathbf A_0=-\eta (\mathbf p{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}^T)^+$. For any other global minimiser $\mathbf A$ of $f$, we have $\|\mathbf A_0\|_F<\|\mathbf A\|_F$, where $\|\cdot\|_F$ denotes Frobenius norm.

Comment: Thank for your nice answer.